# How to stream live video using MPEG-DASH?

Tags: video, live-streaming, mpeg-dash

This is a beginner-level question. I've been reading about MPEG DASH as the new standard for streaming on the Internet. I've been trying to figure out how to setup a server for streaming live video over MPEG-DASH, but all my searches seem to return for progressively streaming a pre-recorded video (using MP4Box and related technologies).

How can I setup streaming with an MPEG DASH server and client interface? It's best if there is some GUI available, as I plan to allow my clients to stream video across my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made pretty good experience with [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) so far - they also offer a [online tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/blog/scalable-live-video-streaming-nginx-plus-bitmovin/), which might be handy, if you are not too familiar with this domain yet. If you prefer a fully GUI based service, you can also give the solution from [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/dash-hls-live-streaming/) a try.

Answer (score 0):

For a free option, the [DashCast](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/dashcast/) utility that comes with mp4box can be used. Commercial encoder products such as [Harmonic ProMedia Live](http://www.harmonicinc.com/product/promedia-live) also offer semi-usable GUIs but tend to be quite expensive. [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/) offers DASH encoding in the cloud, which might be a good middle ground.

Overall, live streaming DASH is considerably more complex to set up than on-demand videos. Expect a lot of experimentation and troubleshooting to be necessary. I have so far not found a DASH live streaming setup I am entirely happy with.